# Can we set an object attribute dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is an attribute of an object possible dynamically?

Attribute name is:
pergunta1item
pergunta2item

This data is dynamically generated.

I tried this way

```
{{ object.data.pesquisa+var.id+item }}
```

But, did not work.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this Jinja?  We need a *lot* more information.

Comment: Just use a list?

Comment: "Is an attribute of an object possible dynamically?" - it's not clear what you're asking. Did you mean: "can we set an object attribute dynamically?" if so the answer is "yes"

Comment: Hi Phix, This is Django

Comment: Hi Alfasin, Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct the attribute name as a string, then [use `getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to look it up on the parent object, replacing:

```
object.data.pesquisa+var.id+item
```

with:

```
# We're looking up an attribute of object.data
# with a dynamically generated name
getattr(object.data, 'pesquisa{}item'.format(var.id))
```

Mind you, as others have mentioned, a numbered set of items should probably be handled as a single `list` (or `tuple`, or `dict`, depending on needs) with a consistent name, so you can just do:

```
object.data.pesquisaitems[var.id]
```

to look up a dynamic index on the fixed name, but if your data source can't be changed, `getattr` is the way to go here.

Comment: thank you so much ShadowRanger. Its work.

Answer (score -2):

Of course we can.What you need to do is add a new attribution and assigned to the old value,then delete the old attribution.

```
def motify_attri(d,newattr,oldattr):
    d[newattr] = d[oldattr]
    d.pop(oldattr)

d = dict(key1='a',key2='2')
print(d)
motify_attri(d,'key3','key2')
print(d)
```

Then:

```
{'key2': '2', 'key1': 'a'}
{'key3': '2', 'key1': 'a'}
[Finished in 0.0s]
```

Comment: How can I do it? I'm new to python.